# Enviar dados para o servidor com javascript e depois recupera-los

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Gente eu estou com seguinte problema, preciso enviar os dados de uma pagina para o servidor e depois conseguir recuperar esses dados, estava vendo uma opção de enviar esses dados da pagina com um evento javascript.

Pensei no evento onkeyup  porem nada viável por que a quantidade de requisição seria absurda.

Alguém tem uma opção melhor para enviar esses dados e depois recuperar eles? Pensei em salvar no cache, porem ainda não encontrei uma opção viável acho que por que tenho pouca experiencia com javascript.

Então minhas duvidas são essas qual evento eu poderia usar para enviar os dados pro servidor e depois recupera-los usando javascript e qual uma boa opção de salvar os dados dessa minha tela em cache e toda vez que eu precisar desses dados eu recuperar eles.

Eu possuo uma aplicação Java web com CDI e Primefaces, e nessa aplicação eu possuo um componente onde eu crio algumas abas para cada tela que eu quiser acessar. O problema em questão é que ao transitar por essas telas eu atualizo via ajax, porem estou tendo alguns problemas, em relação a isso, e acabei tirando essa atualização que era feita com ajax e queria uma forma de não perder esses dados ao mudar de aba e pensei no javascript para fazer isso.

Comment: Tente, por favor, expor melhor sua pergunta com exemplos. Edite ela.

Comment: O momento de enviar seria ao trocar de aba. Mas se quiser enviar tudo de uma vez, já pensou em usar o localStorage? Se explicar melhor como está fazendo, adicionando código eu elaboro um exemplo para você.

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia seria você salvar a cada mudança de aba, no onkeyup é inviável.